# Exit status of ls command on positional parameters

Tags: linux, bash, function, arguments

I have a function 'exit_status' that takes two arguments. $1 is a directory (for a backup rsync script) and $2 (getStatus) is used to set the exit status of a ls on $1 and return the value to the caller. If the exit status is equal to 0, the backup will start.

I would like to rewrite this function to take at least 3 positional parameters, a source and destination path and return the exit status. I would like the function to be able to handle the event I want to pass more than two directories to check. Maybe I might pass several source directories and a destination.

I am not set on the function returning the exit status but am just looking for the best way to check all directories have an exit status of 0 for the caller to execute the backup. If one or more directories have a non-zero return to exit.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Drive paths
testOffSiteBkup1="/mnt/hotswp/testoffsitebkup1/"

exit_status () {
  local _cmd="/bin/ls -al $1 > /dev/null"
  local _getStatus=$2
  eval $_cmd
  local _status=$?
  eval $_getStatus=$_status
}

exit_status $testOffSiteBkup1 getStatus
if [ $getStatus -eq 0 ] ; then
  echo "$testOffSiteBkup1 is present."
  rsync ......
else
  echo "$testOffSiteBkup1 is NOT present."
  exit
fi
```

Comment: How firm are you on using bash? I'm of the opinion that pure shell scripts start to fall apart as complexity increases, where using something like Perl or Python come into their own.

Comment: There is *no reason* to put that `ls` command in a string and then use `eval` it. Don't do that. Also why are you bothering to do this indirection stuff when you could just return the value from the function directly?

Comment: are you are aware of the `$?` variable in the shell? It is the returned value (0-255) from the previously executed cmd. You can alway capture that and process it with condition logic. As a minimal case: `/bin/ls nonesuch;ls_stat=$?;case $ls_stat in 0) echo ok ;; * ) echo err=$ls_stat;;esac` Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without a function and `ls -l` command using test command

For example to check whether both source directory and destination directory exists you can use the following two lines

```
test -d $source && test -d $destination 
status=$(echo $?)
```